# How to serialize BigDecimal to map value with jackson?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Having troubles with serializing BigDecimal object to Map using jackson version 2.7.3 (I can't change this version on my project). It's always serialized as Double. 
Code I use for serialization:

```
public static Map<String, Object> serializeToMap(Object pojo) {
    return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(pojo, new HashMap<String, Object>() {}.getClass());
}
```

Tried to add:

`@JsonSerialize(typing = JsonSerialize.Typing.STATIC, as = BigDecimal.class)`

and used serializer:

```
public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    jgen.writeObject(value.toString());
}
```

Is it possible to serialize it as BigDecimal?

Comment: When you say you want a Map, are you saying that you want all the internal member variables and their values from within BigDecimal, instead of the decimal value itself?  If not, what EXACTLY are your expectations for the JSON?  Please provide an example.

Comment: I want BigDecimal fields to be BigDecimal fields (as value) in Map, others (such as String, Integer) should stay themselves. For example BigDecimal value Entry<String, BigDecimal>, String value Entry<String,String>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by replacing serialization with:

```
return new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS)
    .convertValue(pojo, new HashMap<String, Object>() {}.getClass());
```

Comment: if your question is answered by this answer, please mark it as accepted answer. even though you have asked question. So that it will move to answered questions scetion

Comment: I have to wait 1 day before I can accept my own answer